# A ﬁrst-term expansion of the solution of the ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

> Get a ﬁrst-term expansion of the solution of $$εy''+y'+ y = 0, \text{where } y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 1$$ that is valid for large values of $t$.

I tried the usual approach with two time scales $t$ and $s=ε^a t$. Assuming $$y \sim y_0 + ε^b y_1$$ I get stuck immediately after writing it out since I can't see any obvious choice of $a$ and $b$.

**Added**: here is how I wrote it out: $$ε (\partial^2_t+2ε^a\partial_t \partial_s+ε^{2a}\partial^2_s)(y_0 + ε^b y_1) + (\partial_t + ε^a \partial_s)(y_0 + ε^b y_1) + (y_0 + ε^b y_1)=0$$
If we set $a=1$ and $b=1$, then $O(1)$ gives $$\partial_t y_0 + y_0 = 0$$ which can not satisfy our initial conditions.

So we want some other terms to be in $O(1)$ but both possible choices, namely $a = -1/2$ and $a = -1$, give us $1/ε$ in front of some terms.

Comment: Write out what you got, give some more detail so we don't have to re-do all your work.

Comment: Two timing is not even necessary here, you can do a boundary layer expansion at $t=0$, and everything works out well finding the uniform approximation.

Comment: @David: The thing is that I got it from Holmes's "Introduction to Perturbation Methods" and the exercise is in "Chapter 3 Multiple Scales".

Comment: You do have to go to the next equation (i.e. for $y_1$) to solve this. See the section preceding this example in Holmes' book, there is a worked example very similar to this. It is true that this doesn't work out very nicely though.

Answer (score -2):

$$\epsilon y''+y'+y=0 \quad \begin{cases} y(0)=0\\y'(0)=1\end{cases}$$

NOTE :

In special case $\epsilon=0$ the solution of $y'+y=0$ is $y=ce^{-t}$

The condition $y(0)=0$ implies $c=0$ and the solution is trivial : $y(x)=0$

So, with the specified conditions, the solution of $\epsilon y''+y'+y=0$ tends to $y(x)=0$ when $\epsilon\to 0$. But the condition $y'(0)=1$ is ignored.

BRUT FORCE SOLVING METHOD :

With the eigen values $\epsilon r^2+r+1=0 \quad\to\quad r=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-4\epsilon}}{2\epsilon}$ the general solution is :
$$y=c_1 e^{r_1t}+c_2 e^{r_2t} \quad 
\begin{cases}
r_1=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1-4\epsilon}}{2\epsilon} \sim -1-\epsilon\\
r_2=\frac{-1-\sqrt{1-4\epsilon}}{2\epsilon} \sim -\frac{1}{\epsilon}
\end{cases}$$
With conditions $y(0)=0=c_1+c_2$ and $y'(0)=1=r_1c_1+r_2c_2$ leading to $c_1=-c_2=\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{1-4\epsilon}}$
$$y=\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{1-4\epsilon}} \left( e^{\frac{-1+\sqrt{1-4\epsilon}}{2\epsilon} t}- e^{\frac{-1-\sqrt{1-4\epsilon}}{2\epsilon} t}\right)$$
$$y \sim \epsilon\left( e^{-t}- e^{-\frac{t}{\epsilon}}\right)$$
Bringing it back into the ODE and into the two conditions shows that it agrees for the first approximate.

This approch makes clear the difficulty when it is assumed that $y(t)\sim y_0(t)+\epsilon^b y_1(t)$ :

First, we have $y_0(t)=0$ .  Second, we have $\begin{cases} b=1\\ y_1(t)=e^{-t}\end{cases}$ . This is OK up to this point.

But the term $-\epsilon e^{-\frac{t}{\epsilon}}$is missing. This is acceptable for $\epsilon>0$ and $t$ large because if $\frac{t}{\epsilon}$ is large, the missing term $\epsilon e^{-\frac{t}{\epsilon}} \sim 0$.

On the other hand, keeping only the term $\epsilon e^{-t}$ doesn't satisfy the condition $y'(0)=1$.

Nevertheless, on the common sens of perturbation, I think that an acceptable answer to the question is :
$$y(t)\sim\epsilon e^{-t}$$

Comment: This is not using perturbation theory, you have solved the equation exactly then taken a series expansion of it.

Comment: @David : Of course, what I intended to do is comparing the results from different methods of solving. I would cite Carl Friedrich Gauss : "Of course, for all calculus of this kind, it behaves so that all what can be done with it can be done without it." (approximate translation). Apparently, you didn't catch the interest of the most important part of my answer, at the end : the interpretation of the result of the comparison.

Comment: I just don't think your answer helps the OP, they were asking about one particular method. Why not give an answer using multiple scales?